# The distance from a point to a line (2 defined points) with a vector

Tags: geometry

This is similar to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757318/distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-defined-by-2-points),

What would be the distance to the line from the point with an angle (not the shortest distance directly towards the line from the point), like 135 deg, or 90 deg, or 45 deg? [An example is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y01GT.jpg)

I have already tried using the Pythagorean Theorem to find a side length, then use that side length with its hyp. length, or some awkward math to find the distance, but that doesn't work.

Comment: That picture shows some lines and points, but I have no idea what the question actually is. What does "the distance along a rotation?" even mean?

Comment: Let me try restating your question for you, and you can tell me if it's what you want: Given a point, $(2, 2)$ in the example picture, and a direction (measured as an angle counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis, so the three short segments correspond to directions 45, 90, and 135 degrees reading right to left), find the distance from the point to the line segment between two other points (in the figure, $(-5, 5) and $(9, 5), for example).  One problem: What would be the answer you'd want if the direction, in this example, were $-45$ degrees?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited it.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: In other words, what I need is the point on the line that the point with a specific angle is intersected at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P$ be the point labeled $(2,2)$, and let $A$ and $B$ be the two points defining the line. Let
$$
v = (\cos t, \sin t)
$$
where $t$ is the specified angle. (If you're using degrees, be sure to use a cosine and sine function that consume degrees, for instance by setting your calculator to "degrees").

Let $w = B - A$; in the example, 
$$
w = (9, 5) - (-5, 5) = (14, 0)
$$

A point $Q$ at distance $s$ along the ray leaving $P$ in direction $t$ is given by 
$$
Q = P + sv
$$
In the example, that's 
$$
(2, 2) + s(\cos t, \sin t) = (2 + s\cos t, 2 + s \sin t).
$$
The ray from $A$ to this point is given by $Q - A$, i.e., 
$$
r = (P + sv) - A = (P-A) + sv
$$
You want to find the value of $s$ that makes this ray parallel to $w$; the way to do that is to make it perpendicular to 
$$
w^{\perp} = (-w_y, w_x)
$$
Using dot products, which I don't really want to explain, that means that you want
$$
[ (P-A) + sv ] \cdot w^\perp = 0
$$
and solving for $s$, we get
\begin{align}
(P-A) \cdot w^\perp + s v \cdot w^\perp &= 0\\
(A-P) \cdot w^\perp \&= s v \cdot w^\perp \\
\frac{(A-P) \cdot w^\perp}{v  \cdot w^\perp} \&= s.
\end{align}

And now, having found $s$, you want to compute 
$$
Q = P + sv
$$
Here $s$ is the distance to the intersection point, and $Q$ is the point itself.

I'm going to carry this out for your example, with an angle $t$ of $30$ degrees. The cosine and sine of $30$ degrees are $0.866$ and $0.5$ (roughly). So 
$$
v = (0.866, 0.5).
$$
And as we already computed above, $w = (14, 0)$, so 
$$
w^\perp = (-0, 14) = (0, 14). 
$$

The ray $A-P$ is $(-5, 5) - (2, 2) = (-7, 3)$. So computing:
$$
\frac{(A-P) \cdot w^\perp}{v  \cdot w^\perp} \&= s.
$$
we get
$$
\frac{(-7, 3) \cdot (0, 14)}{(0.855, 0.5)  \cdot (0, 14)} \&= \frac{42}{7} = 6
$$
So the intersection point is $6$ units away from $P$.

And in fact 
$$
Q = P + sv = (2, 2) + 6 (0.866, 0.5) = (2, 2) + (5.196, 3) = (7.196, 5). 
$$

You can mimic this computation for any direction $t$ that you like. If the value you compute for $s$ is negative or infinity, then the ray you've chosen doesn't intersect the given line between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused over s. In the final product, (-7,3)*(0,14), the x's and y's are multiplied, then they are added? So like (-7 * 0) + (3 * 14) = 42, Is that correct?

Comment: Nevermind that, I was was correct. When I try 180 degrees for the desired angle (which will never intersect the line), 2.4496... is returned. How will I determine if an angle is out of bounds of the line?

Comment: Oh wait it's 2.44 e16 ok